# php is not showing the else-block

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm trying to learn about `session_start()` but when i run the file, it only show what is inside the

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& isset($_SESSION['password'])==$password) {
?>
    <a href="home.php">log out</a>
<?php } ?>
```

and not showing `else{...}` and even after i click log out, it won't print anything in else statement and only print inside the if statement. I use another file to do the log out proses but i don't know the right code for `session_destroy()`

here's the logout.php code below:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
session_destroy(); 
header("location: home.php"); 
?>
```

here's the full code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("DB/db.php");
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['password']=$password;
$_SESSION['is_log_in'] = true; 
 ?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="blank"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <nav id="bar">
            <div id="submen">
                <form id="sir">
                <input type="Search" name="search" placeholder="Search.." id="search">
            </form>
                <a  href="wallpaper.php" id="menu">Walpaper</a>
                <a  href="art.php" id="menu">Art</a>
                <a  href="photo.php" id="menu">Photos</a>
                <a  href="image.php" id="menu">Image</a>
 <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& isset($_SESSION['password'])==$password) {?>

                <?php echo $username?>
                    <a href="logout.php">log out</a>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</table>
    <?php } else {
    ?>
                <a href="log_in.php" id="member">login</a>
                <a href="register.php" id="member">register</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </table>
    <?php } ?>

    </body>
   </html>
```

UPDATE for log in script

```
<?php
session_start();

include("DB/db.php"); 

if ($_GET['log']=='out'){
    session_destroy();
} 
if ($_POST['user']){
    $sql = "Select password from user where username = '".$_POST['user']."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)){ 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ($row['password'] == md5($_POST['pass'])) {

            $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
        }else{

            $pesan = "Username and password mismatch";
        }
    }else{

        $pesan = "please register";
    }
}   

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    if ($_SESSION['login']) {

        echo "text";
    }else{
        ?>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="post" action="rahasia.php">
            Username: <input type="text" name="user">
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="register.php">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="register"> 
        </form>

        <?php
    }
    echo $pesan;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

where have i gone wrong

Comment: `$_SESSION['username']=$username` - and where is `$username` coming from …?

Comment: this `isset($_SESSION['password'])==$password` will never be true (unless `$password` is a boolean)

Comment: What are you expecting from `isset($_SESSION['password'])==$password`?

Comment: @CBroe $username is from database

Comment: @Jeff - Actually, that will always be true if the session is set and `$password` isn't empty. Two equal signs doesn't check for types: https://3v4l.org/T3FaK

Comment: @kerbholz i think `isset($_SESSION['password'])==$password` is used for check the condition

Comment: @Abraham _"I think"_ - isn't this your code? Also, _"check the condition"_ doesn't really say anything. Anyway. `isset()` returns true if the variable is set and not null. Comparing it to a string is pretty useless.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can it because of the database.php? for using username for access the mysql?

Comment: The problem is that you're mixing up the users username/password and the database credentials. Those are different things and has _nothing_ to do with each other.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson if I have the same variable as database.php it doesn't matter?

Comment: But you're setting the session regardless if the user has logged in or not. In that case, why even have a logged in check at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your $_SESSION vars are always set, and $password always equals $_SESSION['password'].

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username; // null, plus notice in error_log
$_SESSION['password']=$password; // null, plus notice in error_log
```

Unless those two vars are set in `include("DB/db.php");`, in which case that is bad practice. Can you paste db.php to see what is happening inside?

UPDATE.

Okay so the vars are being set. This now means:

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username; // a
$_SESSION['password']=$password; // 123456789
```

Therefore they will still match. You need to refactor these lines to function properly. Are you sure the mysql credentials is what you want for your logged in user
?

Comment: `<?php 
$server="localhost";
$username="a";
$password="123456789";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);
 mysqli_select_db($con,"justapic");`

that what is in the db.php

Comment: @Abraham - So you're setting the sessions username and password to hard coded database auth values from your db-file? That makes zero sense. As long as you don't manually set your database username and password as `null` in your db-file, the user will always be logged in.

Comment: so the problem is lays on the `db.php`?and i must change the variable for $username?

Comment: do each of your sites users have their own user account on mysql? i doubt it, and if so, they shouldn't. DB user and pass is a separate set of credentials that your server uses to hook up to the db. it has nothing to do with your users credentials!

Comment: @Abraham - The problem is the logic in your code in general. If a user successfully loges in, you should set a session, like the _users_ username/id or similar. When the user then logs out, you destroy the session. Then you only need to check if the session is set on the other requests. If you manually set the session values on every request, it will be like the user is always logged in.

Comment: Can we see the log in script?

Comment: yeah in your question might be a better place, thats unreadable